# Is there a way to submit functions from __main__ using Python RQ

Tags: python, python-rq

In a similar vein to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012817/python-reddis-queue-valueerror-functions-from-the-main-module-cannot-be-pro/31032356?noredirect=1#comment84885229_31032356), is there any way to submit a function defined in the same file to python-rq?  @GG_Python who asked me to create a new question for this.

Usage example:

```
# somemodule.py
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

def somefunc():
    do_something()

q = Queue(connection=Redis('redis://redis'))
q.enqueue(somefunc)
```

Yes, I know the answer is to define somefunc in someothermodule.py and then in the above snippet `from someothermodule import somefunc`, but I really don't want to.  Maybe I'm being too much of a stickler for form, but somefunc really belongs in the same file in which it is enqueued (in practice, somefunc takes a docker container name and spawns it). I'd really like the whole thing to be self contained instead of having two modules.

I noticed, digging through python-rq source code, that Queue.enqueue can actually take a string rather than the actual module, so I was hoping I could maybe pass `somemodule.somefunc`, but no so such luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/rq/rq/blob/master/rq/queue.py), rq is just checking your function's `__module__` attribute, which can be trivially changed. The question is, *why* does rq restrict you from enqueueing jobs from `__main__`? There must be some reason, and there is: the function's module must be importable by the worker. `__main__` is not, because your main module is not named `__main__.py` on disk. See "Considerations for Jobs" toward the bottom of [this page](http://python-rq.org/docs/).

Also, your script has top-level (non-definition) code in it that will be invoked anew each time it is imported by a worker, which you probably don't want to do, as it will create new queues and fill them with jobs when each worker starts, infinitely. If you want to enqueue a function in your main module, you can and should prevent this recursive behavior with an `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard.

If you want to keep the function and its enqueuement in a single module, my suggestion is that you don't put any top-level code in it besides function and/or class definitions. Anything that would be top-level code, write as a function (named e.g. `main()`). Then write a "dummy" main module that imports your real one and kicks off the processing.

Example:

*somemodule.py*

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

def somefunc():
    do_something()

def main():
    q = Queue(connection=Redis('redis://redis'))
    q.enqueue(somefunc)

# if the user tried to execute this module, import the right one for them.
# somemodule is then imported twice, once as __main__ and once as somemodule,
# which will use a little extra memory and time but is mostly harmless
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import mainmodule
```

*mainmodule.py*

```
import somemodule
somemodule.main()
```

You could also just change the `__module__` attribute of your function to the actual name of your module on disk, so that it can be imported. You can even write a decorator to do this automatically:

```
from sys import modules
from from os.path import basename, splitext

def enqueueable(func):
    if func.__module__ == "__main__":
        func.__module__, _ = splitext(basename(modules["__main__"].__file__))
    return func

@enqueueable
def somefunc():
    do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from redis import Redis
    from rq import Queue

    q = Queue(connection=Redis('redis://redis'))
    q.enqueue(somefunc)
```

For simplicity, the decorator assumes your module is a single file importable under its filename with the `.py` extension stripped off. You *could* be using a package for your main module, in which things will get more complicated... so don't do that.